# Tensorflow 2 ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: Custom Loss Function

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, loss-function

So in my Tensorflow2 model, I am getting the error: "ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable"

According to: [TensorFlow: 'ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37889125/tensorflow-valueerror-no-gradients-provided-for-any-variable) the problem is that I am extracting values out of the tf.tensors, manipulating them, and then returning a loss value. I need to be doing everything using tf.tensor operations.

The problem is, I don't know how to do what I want to do with tensor operations. What I want to do is compute the probability of y_pred with respect to a measure defined by the Multivariate Gaussian centered at y_true with a set covariance matrix. The problem is, this needs to happen for every row in y_pred with respect to its corresponding row in y_true.

How can I do this via the tensor operations? Sorry I am very new to TF2.

The code is below:

`python`

```
import numpy
import tensorflow as tf
import scipy.stats as stats

def probability_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    cov = 0.005*numpy.eye(2)
    loss = 0    
    for v, val in enumerate(y_true.numpy()):
        dist = stats.multivariate_normal(mean=val, cov=cov)
        loss += -numpy.log(dist.pdf(y_pred[v]))
    tf_loss = tf.convert_to_tensor(loss, dtype=numpy.float32)
    return tf_loss
```

Comment: Have a look at [tensorflow probability](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/distributions) .

Comment: @gobrewers14 Thanks -- I will. Can I just throw in a tensor into one of their distros and get what I want? I dont want some sort of Nx2 multivariate tensor distribution, but multiple 2 dimensional multivariate gaussians.